# Get depth on mouseclick with kinect

Tags: c#, opencv, kinect

I'm starting a project with Kinect.

The frist thing I want to do is let the user click on an object and the program returns how far that object is from the kinect.

My code:

```
private void colorImg_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    double distance;
    System.Windows.Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(colorImg);
    distance = position.X + (position.Y * 640);
    int af = (int)distance;
    int depth = depthPixels[af].Depth;
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("" + depth);
}
```

But that always returns `0`, the problem is that the Depth attribute of the `deptPixels` is always `0` from the start. With a breakpoint I checked at this line, and for every pixel the depth is `0`. But why?

```
this.depthPixels = new DepthImagePixel[this.sensor.DepthStream.FramePixelDataLength];
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Are you're `depthPixels` being updated continually? If they're only updated once, e.g. on your class initialization, then I would expect that the data will always stay the same and probably the default (0).

Comment: I'm sorry for the dumb question, do I need to put the code (depthPixels = new DepthImagePixel[this.sensor.DepthStream.FramePixelDataLength];) in my sensor_AllFramesReady void. (Not working) How would you update this?

Comment: Could give it ago! Disclamer: never worked with Kinect.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it's not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason may be that your `DepthImagePixel[]` is not being populated.

The line of code you've shown

```
this.depthPixels = new DepthImagePixel[this.sensor.DepthStream.FramePixelDataLength];
```

initializes the array but does not add any data to it, so I would expect all values within to be zero.

When your class is initialized, you should add an event which updates this:

```
this.sensor.DepthFrameReady += this.SensorDepthFrameReady;
```

and add this to the class:

```
private void SensorDepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
    {
        if (depthFrame != null)
        {
            depthFrame.CopyDepthImagePixelDataTo(this.depthPixels);
        }
        else
        {
            // depthFrame is null because the request did not arrive in time
        }
    }
}
```

This was lifted (roughly) verbatim from [MSDN - Getting and Displaying Depth Data in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131029.aspx).